# Not able to cross check two variables using $.each() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a variable 'Habits', it is assigned some default values. When the page loads I fetch the values from the database in json format using ajax. When the ajax call is successful I cross check the values in the **Habits** variable using the **$.each()** function. It is not working when I give **r.index** in **if** condition in **$.each()** function, but it is working when I give **r.Smoking** or **r.Drinking**. Please help me to solve this problem

Habits variable is defined:

```
   var Habits={
    "Smoking":"No",
    "Drinking":"No"
       }
```

My ajax function

```
$.ajax{
    url:'getvalue',
    data:data,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(r)
     {
        $.each(Habits,function(index, value)
        {
            if(r.index=="Yes")
        {
            $("#"+index).attr('checked=checked');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#"+index).removeAttr('checked');
        }

          }

      }
    }
```

json data:

```
{"Smoking":"Yes","Drinking":"Yes"}
```

Comment: What is the intended function of the defaults-variable `Habits`? If your code is fixed, as per Arun P Johny's suggestion, for instance, you're just using it to specify the keys to iterate over; and you might just as well have done that with `r`. Might a `Habits` variable be set to `Yes` and should that affect the output when that property is missing in `r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see

1. To set the checked property you need to use .prop() instead of .attr()
2. Since `index` is a variable holding the actual key name you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Try

```
$.ajax {
    url: 'getvalue',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (r) {
        $.each(Habits, function (index, value) {
            $("#" + index).prop('checked', r[index] == "Yes");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks now its working perfectly, And can u tell what was the problem in using .attr()